# How can I replace string in a file?

Tags: sed

I have the following line in a file, I would like to insert `\N` between two comma

```
20121128020001,2012-11-28 02:00:01.000,,,,,,,3.80,,,,,
```

I tried to use seed

```
sed -i 's/,,/,\\N,/g' Test.CSV
```

Where I get the following result:

```
0121128020001,2012-11-28 02:00:01.000,\N,,\N,,\N,,3.80,\N,,\N,,
```

I could run two times, but in a huge file it is inefficient. How can I fix the sed command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Perl with lookaheads, so that the second comma is not part of the match:

```
perl -pe 's/,(?=,)/,\\N/g'
```

Or, use the same expression twice on the same line:

```
sed 's/,,/,\\N,/g;s/,,/,\\N,/g'
```

Comment: perl is way faster, tested for large files >1GB

Comment: @run Uhm.. really? On my box `sed` is 2x faster!